# Solubility and wetting of substances in water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, analytical-chemistry

We have seen that, when we pour salt in water then it gets dissolved, that means it is soluble in water. But when we pour sand into water then it doesn't dissolve in water, that means it is insoluble, but still sand gets wet. But there are certain substances which doesn't get wet by water for example, sulfur particles don't get wet by water but wet in oil, as I was studying about froth floatation method.

My question is that:

- What is the difference between solubility and wetting in water ?
- What is the reason that the sulfur particle doesn't get wet by water?

Comment: Soluble gets dissolved, and wettable just gets wet. It is not going to be any simpler than that. The examples you gave yourself.

Comment: But what is the reason that sulphur particle doesn't get wet by water in froath floatation method

Comment: The difference is surface tension, and it is, among others, due to differences in polarity.

Comment: You're trying to split hairs. For instance there really isn't a good definition of what "soluble" means, so soluble is by definition a fuzzy measurement.  $\ce{SiO2}$ (quartz, sand) does dissolve in water, just not very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polar/hydrophilic soluble substances get dissolved, like table salt or sugar.

Polar/hydrophilic insoluble substances get wet, as they attract water, like sand, or limestone.

Nonpolar/hydrophobic insoluble substances do not get wet, as they repulse water, like wax, teflon or silanized glass.

Comment: Nonpolar molecules do not easily dissolve in water and are hydrophobic, they become squeezed together.

Comment: What does this squeezed together means?

Comment: Water surface tension causes water has more energy if it has larger surface what leads the system to have   as small contact surface water Vs hydrophobic substance via small but real force.

Comment: Do all the non polar molecules doesn't get wet in water???

Comment: Does any molecule get wet ?

Comment: Molecules doesn't get wet

Comment: When we see through our naked eyes those salt being added to water then after sometimes salt get vanished which we say salt get dissolved in water

Comment: And in molecular level if we see then we say salt molecules get broken down into its constituent ions

Comment: And when we see sand being added to water through our naked eyes.... after sometimes when we see sand then we say the sand gets wet by water

Comment: But what would be happening in the molecular level...???

Answer (score 0):

The water molecules undergo a sort of attraction between them. This attraction is due to $\ce{H}$ atoms being attracted by the oxygen atoms of neighboring water molecules. At the surface of the water this attraction produces a sort of "skin" due to the attraction of the molecules between them. If a solid is touching this surface, it may produce a similar attraction between its molecules and water. This is the case when the outer part of the solid contains the same $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{O}$ atoms as water. In that case, the attraction between water and these foreign atoms allow water to wet the solid. And even to "climb" a couple of millimeters inside the stuff.

Sulfur has no $\ce{H}$ or $\ce{O}$ atoms. It cannot make bonds with water. So water molecules on the water surface refuse to break their bonds for wetting this foreign solids.

Comment: a sort of skin means